# Replace a line in a .txt file

Tags: c++

I want to replace dates in a line in a .txt file.

The line might look like this:

```
1234    24.08    24.09.
```

Can I find this line by just searching for `1234` and replace the dates `24.08` and `24.09`?

Comment: look at istringstream , read one word at a time , process 2nd, 3rd words and change them

Comment: are the spacings tabs or spaces?

Comment: I used setw() command when writing to file

Answer (score 1):

If your replacement has the same quantity of characters as the text in the file, then go ahead and seek to the position and overwrite the text (see std::ostream::seekp).

Otherwise, you will have to write to a new file.

Files can't expand in the middle.